# Inventory Management system using React TypeError: Cannot read property 'map' of undefined

Tags: arrays, reactjs, undefined, array.prototype.map

```
import React from 'react';

function StockEventsTable(props){
    const {stockEvents} = props // same as const stockEvents = props.stockEvents
    return (
        <div className='StockEventTable'>
            {stockEvents.map(event => ( 
               <p>Qunatity: {event.qty}</p> 
            ))} 
        </div>
    )
  }

  export default StockEventsTable;
```

```
import React from 'react'; 
import './App.css'; )
import StockEventsTable from './components/StockEventsTable';

const fetchedProducts = [
  {id: 1, name: 'Super Maroo'} ]
  
const fetchedStockEvents = [
   {id: 1, type: 'add', qty: 100, product: fetchedProducts[0]}, 
   {id: 2, type: 'remove', qty: -20, product: fetchedProducts[0]},
   {id: 3, type: 'remove', qty: -10, product: fetchedProducts[0]}
 ]

function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>The StockApp </h1>
      <StockEventsTable 
        products={fetchedProducts} 
        stockevents={fetchedStockEvents} />

    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Please help. The program doesn't render when I include the .map(). Before that, it works well. I am learning and following a tutorial for react, and everything looks like the sample code but I can't compile mine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change `stockEvents` to `stockevents` (all lowercase)

```
 const { stockevents } = props; 
  return (
    <div className="StockEventTable">
      {stockevents.map((event) => (
        <p>Qunatity: {event.qty}</p>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
```

working code - https://codesandbox.io/s/late-glitter-me3if?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should change `stockEvents` to `stockevents` (all lowercase), try change the code

Example:

```
function StockEventsTable(props){
    const {stockevents} = props // same as const stockEvents = props.stockEvents
    return (
        <div className='StockEventTable'>
            {stockevents&&stockevents.map(event => ( 
               <p>Qunatity: {event.qty}</p> 
            ))} 
        </div>
    )
  }
```

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

yeah, so you are messing around with wrong map **syntax**. This is a great link for in-built prototypes and function. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

It goes something like this:

```
 <div className='StockEventTable'>
        {stockEvents.map(event => **(** //this should be curly braces
           <p>Qunatity: {event.qty}</p> 
        **)**)} // and end with one here too
```

and this too, Change **stockEvents to stockevents** (all lowercase)
I didn't made the changes, so you spot them and follow the course along and if you are new to JS, try freecodecamp.org 's JS and react, they are great learning spot. Have a good Day!

Comment: Thank you very much!

Comment: my bad you were using shorthand return for jsx, yeah I missed that, learnt it recently and also it is a good practice to &&stockEvents.length >0 condition before mapping since optional chaining doesn't works in this case